# variable comparison

Tags: java, android

I am creating android application with login. It sends username and password entered in application to php script on remote server, php script checks if username and pass are correct and, if yes it prints 1, or if wrong it prints 2. There are no html tags returned, just number 1 or 2.

this is code that i am using

```
   response = SimpleHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://......myscript.php", postParameters);
   String res = response.toString();


   if (res.equals("1")) {

       error.setText("ok");

   }
   else if (res.equals("2")) {

       error.setText("fail");
   }
   else {

       error.setText(res);
   }
```

After i get response variable error.setText(res) is working and it shows 1 or 2 depending on correct or incorrect username/pass. But, when i try to "control" the answer (if and else if part of code), nothing happens, and "else" part is executed. I tried to convert res to int by (Integer.parseInt()) but same thing, tried without response.toString, comparing directly response, and everything that i can think of. Where i am mistaking?

Comment: use a log statement like this to print res `Log.i("TAG","##"+res+"##");` ensure that the log looks like `##1##` and not `## 1##` or `##1 ##` or `##1\n##`. it is possible your response contains either spaces, or newlines which would not be immediately apparent when you put it in a TextView

Comment: I checked with log.i and it shows ##2##, so there are no white spaces...what else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a scanner to determine the int:

```
int responseInt = new Scanner(res).nextInt();
//do comparisons with responseInt
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, used res = res.trim() and then converted it to int with Integer.parseInt(res);

Thank you :)